# Nested findElement where first is xpath and second is css, working not as expected

Tags: css, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is how my html source looks like.

```html
      <tr>
        <td class='first'>User Name</td>
        <td class='last'>
          <input/>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Now, when I tried to locate input tag I mistakenly wrote my code like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last>input"))
```

it successfully located the input tag, it seems a bit confusing to me because in my first findElement I've already reached till the td tag now again in second findElement I started from same td tag. I think it should throw NoSuchElement exception.
Again I tried it with different combinations of By methods but it failed to locate and fired the NoSuchElement exception. Even I tried it like below and here it fired the NoSuchElement exception:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last"))
```

can any one please help me with the reason of this abnormal behaviour in first case where it located the input element successfully.

Comment: Please share the full complete HTML with the opening input tag or the URL of the page under test.

Comment: Which DOM element do you wish to locate exactly by the way?

Comment: Why do you try to combine two different types of search qualifiers? As far as it appears to me you could locate the element directly using XPath only.

Comment: @Anirudh I want to locate **input** element and yes it can be done quite easily and by single findElement also. But my point is not about how to locate it where as my point is why it is locating successfully when there is no td inside td.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is essentially correct. And, this is indeed a normal behavior.

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last>input"))
```

The first "findElement" part locates the **td class with class 'last'**. Now, the second "findElement" must locate **an element that resides under the element, located by the first "findElement" part**. And, that's exactly what it does. The cssselector points to the **"input"** tag under the **td class with class 'last'**. It doesn't matter where you have started it. In fact, what matters is the located element is **"input"** only.

Hope this helps.!!

Comment: For the second code in your question, you are trying to select a **td** element under the **'td class with class 'last'**. But, there is no such element under it. That's why it was throwing **NoSuchElementException**. But there is, in fact, an **input element**. Hence, your first line of code worked as it is being directed to that element. You can also use this code too. `WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.cssSelector("input"));`

Comment: if it is true then below should also work fine:  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last"))`  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[@class='last']")).findElement(By.xpath(".//td[@class='last']/input"))`  `driver.findElement(By.className("last").findElement(By.cssSelector("td.last>input"))`  but none of them is working